# Cannot import numpy after building

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, build, intel-mkl, icc

I was building numpy for Python 3 (64-bit) with Intel C++ and Intel MKL on Linux (`3.11-1-amd64`). I got the source from git. I also have installed Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 for Linux.

Here's what I have done:

1. Created an `site.cfg` in the source folder, with content

   ```
   [mkl]
   library_dirs = /opt/intel/mkl/composer_xe_2013/lib/intel64
   include_dirs = /opt/intel/mkl/include
   mkl_libs = mkl_rt
   lapack_libs =
   ```
2. Changed the `self.cc_exe` in `numpy/distutils/intelccompiler.py` into `'icc -O3 -g -fPIC -fp-model strict -fomit-frame-pointer -openmp -xhost'`
3. Added the library paths: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
4. Executed `sudo python3 setup.py config --compiler=intel build_clib --compiler=intel build_ext --compiler=intel install`

After everything has been finished, I launched `python3` and `import numpy`, which gives

```
    $ python3
    Python 3.3.2+ (default, Sep 18 2013, 11:58:01) 
    [GCC 4.8.1] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import numpy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
        from . import add_newdocs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
        from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .type_check import *
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
        import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import multiarray
    ImportError: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But I've checked `/opt/intel/lib/intel64`, the file is just there. Have I missed something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts for the better part of the afternoon. Apparently there is bad blood between scipy and sudo; you'll need to run that command **without** `sudo`. Which means installing with the `--prefix=/I/Have/write/permission/here` or changing permissions of the scipy source directory the error is being thrown on the config-build portion.

Comment: Changing permissions of the scipy source directory to?

Comment: `chmod -R <permissionsettings> <dirname>`  you'll want read/write permissions but check `man chmod` to get make sure you get the correct settings for your role/system.